# Output a var and result of a test with one echo?

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo out some vars and the result of a test:

```
<div class="<?php echo strtolower($data['name']) . strtolower($data['name']) == 'test' && true ? 'yes' : 'no'; ?>">
```

But nothing is output at all.

How can I output both a var and a test?

Comment: can you just clean up the code and figure out what you want to output one line above?

Comment: `strtolower($data['name']) == 'test' && true` WHY the `&& true` ??

Comment: true is for examples sake, it's all legacy code so needs to be done this way.

Comment: Also, you will not see the output as it is inside a div element, as a value for the class attribute. your browser does not display that data without opening up dev tools

Comment: @RiggsFolly maybe just a placeholder for something he removed :)

Comment: "But nothing is output at all." Under what condition? I get `<div class="no">`

Answer (score 5):

Use parentheses to group the ternary.  Also, why `&& true`?

```
<div class="<?php echo strtolower($data['name'])
. (strtolower($data['name']) == 'test' ? 'yes' : 'no'); ?>">
```